# Var declaration overwrites current variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help understanding what I'm doing wrong with my js code.
Basically I have a canvas and a particle that bounces around inside the canvas. What I want is for users to input data in a form and submit it, then the particle will start with their specified values.

The HTML body:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<form id="myForm" >


            X Initial: 
            <input type="text" id="xInit" name="xInit" />
            <br/>

            Y initial: 
            <input type="text" id="yInit" name="yInit" />
            <br/>

            X Velocity: 
            <input type="text" id="xDir" name="xDir" />
            <br/>

            Y Velocity: 
            <input type="text" id="xDir" name="yDir" />
            <br/>


            Change:
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>
```

The particle is it's own class:

```
function particle(x, y, dX, dY) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dX = dX;
    this.dY = dY;
    this.check = checkCollision;
}
```

I initialize the page and submit the form using jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var HEIGHT = 400;
        var WIDTH = 400;
        var p1, xl, yl, xd, yd;
                   ...More code...
            $("form").submit(function(){
                xl = +$("#xInit").val();
                yl = +$("#yInit").val();
                xd = +$("#xDir").val();
                yd = +$("#xDir").val();
                p1 = new particle(xl,yl,xd,yd);
                init();
        });
    });
```

Then lastly, my init() function calls a function draw() to redraw the particle over a set Interval:

```
function init() {
    draw();
    alert(p1.x);
    return setInterval(draw, 10);
}
```

So When I click submit everything works initially, it draws the particle 1 time and then it disappears forever. I believe it's because the **var p1, xl, yl, xd, yd;** keeps re-declaring itself. Is there a way around this? Or a better way to set this up in general?
Many Thanks.

---

## Update

The return false; part worked much appreciated

Comment: where is the `init()` function in relation to the jQuery document ready handler? Is inside this function? or is side-by-side/outside of it?

Comment: We'd probably need to see the 'draw' function (which, unless I'm going crazy, isn't shown here). That's my bet on where the culprit is hiding out.

Comment: Where is the code that updates the particle position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is that your form is getting submitted when you click 'Submit'. That refreshes the page, and your variables get reset.

You must return `false` in the `submit` handler to prevent that:

```
        $("form").submit(function(){
            xl = +$("#xInit").val();
            yl = +$("#yInit").val();
            xd = +$("#xDir").val();
            yd = +$("#xDir").val();
            p1 = new particle(xl,yl,xd,yd);
            init();
            return false; // <======
        });
```